# How to combine several pieces of code in one? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i got a little problem with my code: i got 3 pieces of code, but i can't combine it together.

All three codes put timestamps in different cells when certain cells change.
If I change cell A1, then in cell B1 insert timestamp. If the change in cell A2, then in cell B2 insert timestamp , etc.

Can you help me? Thanks.

```
1)

function onEdit(event) {


  var tsheet = 'Заявки' ; 

  var lcol = 17; 
  var rcol = 17; 
  var tcol = 18;


  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sname = s.getName();
  if (sname == tsheet) {
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var scol = r.getColumn();
    if (scol >= lcol && scol <= rcol) {
      s.getRange(r.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }

}

2)

function onEdit(event) {


  var tsheet = 'Заявки' ; 

  var lcol = 15; 
  var rcol = 15; 
  var tcol = 16;


  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sname = s.getName();
  if (sname == tsheet) {
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var scol = r.getColumn();
    if (scol >= lcol && scol <= rcol) {
      s.getRange(r.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }

}

3) 

function onEdit(event) {


  var tsheet = 'Заявки' ;

  var lcol = 9; 
  var rcol = 9; 
  var tcol = 8;


  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sname = s.getName();
  if (sname == tsheet) {
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var scol = r.getColumn();
    if (scol >= lcol && scol <= rcol) {
      s.getRange(r.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the column specification in an array:

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var tsheet = 'Заявки' ;
  var colspec=[[17,17,18],[15,15,16],[9,9,8]];

  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sname = s.getName();
  if (sname == tsheet) {
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var scol = r.getColumn();
    var i=colspec.length;
    while (i>0) {
      i--;
      if (scol >= colspec[i][0] && scol <= colspec[i][1]) {
        s.getRange(r.getRow(), colspec[i][2]).setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```